# React: Live DOM element position/dimension resolver hook optimization

Tags: javascript, react.js

I implemented the following react hook to get live updates of an element's position and dimensions in the DOM:

```
/**
 * @author devskope
 */

import { useCallback, useRef, useState } from 'react';
import { throttle } from '../limiters';

const useElementDimensions = () => {
  const [dimensions, setDimensions] = useState({});
  const ref = useRef();

  const doUpdate = ({ current: node }) => {
    if (node) {
      const rect = node.getBoundingClientRect();
      const offsetY = Math.round(rect.top + window.scrollY);  // add absolute position to top of viewport
      setDimensions({ offsetY, ...rect });
    }
  };

  const updateDimensions = useCallback((ref, opts = {}) => {
    const { delay = 400 } = opts;
    return throttle(() => doUpdate(ref), delay);  // regulate update rate
  }, []);

  return { dimensions, ref, updateDimensions };
};
```

The hook can be used in a component to obtain the position to the top of an element as follows:

```
import useElementDimensions from '../../lib/hooks/useElementDimensions';

const TopCategories = (props) => {
  const { id,} = props;

  const { dimensions, ref, updateDimensions } = useElementDimensions();

  const offset = dimensions?.offsetY;

  /**
   * Update  dimensions on page scroll, can be hooked to any event or manually triggered
   *
   * How to I trigger this when images load to offset elements or when new elements enter the dom??????
   */
  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', updateDimensions(ref, { delay: 700 }));
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(offset);
  }, [offset]);

  return (
    <div id={id} ref={ref}>
     target element is ${offset} px from the top
    </div>
  );
};
```

How can this implementation be made more efficient/performant?

Thanks.